# Regex with special chars

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I have this regex.

```
/^[\w]|[åäöæøÅÄÖÆØ]$/
```

"tå" is ok but "åå" is not. Why is that? How can I make it accept words starting with åäöæøÅÄÖÆØ?

Comment: Remove the `$`. `[]` denotes a character class.

Comment: *""tå" is ok but "åå" is not."* Well, they both match the expression. `"tå"` matches because it matches the `^[\w]` alternative. `"åå"` matches because it matches the `[åäöæøÅÄÖÆØ]$` alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the `\w` (and `\W`, `\b`, and `\B`) are **English-centric**. `\w` just means `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, where `A-Z` means only the 26 English letters. Other letters are not considered part of a "word" by JavaScript's built-in character classes.

You'll need to build a character class including all of the letters you want to treat as word characters (then use the negated version of that wherever you "non-word character").

But that's not the only problem. Your regular expression says:

> Match one English word character at the beginning of the string, **or** match one of this list of characters at the end of the string.

The `|` operator is fairly greedy, in this case it treats `^[\w]` and `[åäöæøÅÄÖÆØ]$` as the alternatives. I don't get the impression that's what you wanted.

> "tå" is ok but "åå" is not.

I guess it depends on what you mean by "ok". Both match the expression:

```
console.log("tå".match(/^[\w]|[åäöæøÅÄÖÆØ]$/)); // ["t", index: 0, input: "tå"]
console.log("åå".match(/^[\w]|[åäöæøÅÄÖÆØ]$/)); // ["å", index: 1, input: "åå"]
```

`"tå"` matches because it matches the `^[\w]` alternative. `"åå"` matches because it matches the `[åäöæøÅÄÖÆØ]$` alternative.

> How can I make it accept words starting with åäöæøÅÄÖÆØ?

If the goal is to accept only strings containing exactly one word, where "word" includes digits and the underscore (since `\w` does), then:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9_åäöæøÅÄÖÆØ]+$/
```

Comment: @user874774: It's not clear quite what you're looking for. If your goal is see if the string contains *just one word*, then yes, put `$` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think it fails? I would not put the \w in square brackets but various systems seem to allow that and both the following match the text being tested.

Javascript

```
var test = 'åå';
if (test.match(/^[\w]|[åäöæøÅÄÖÆØ]$/)) { alert("Match"); }
```

PHP

```
echo(preg_match("/^[\w]|[åäöæøÅÄÖÆØ]$/","åå")."</br>");
```

What are you trying to achieve here?